# Trouble aligning content within div

Tags: html, css

I have a group of three divs, each containing a `.header` class and `.content` class. I've mostly aligned the `.header` class as it should be, but having an issue getting the `.content` class to align below the header and have about 10-15px of padding on all sides, with the text floated left for both the header and content. This should have an easy solution, but I'm just not seeing it.

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <section>
      <ul class="nav nav-wizard">
        <li class="active">
          <h5 class="header">
          Header
          </h5>
          <p class="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolorset amicum
          </p>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <h5 class="header">
            Header
          </h5>
          <p class="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolorset amicum
          </p>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <h5 class="header">
            Header
        </h5>
          <p class="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolorset amicum
          </p>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
li {
  width: 190px;
}

ul.nav-wizard:before {
  position: absolute;
}

ul.nav-wizard li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px 0 30px;
  margin: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 46px;
}

ul.nav-wizard li a {
  color: #428bca;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.nav-wizard li a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

li:last-child:before {
  border-left: 16px #6633cc;
}

li:last-child:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border: 31px solid transparent;
  border-left: 16px solid #6633cc;
  border-right: 0;
  top: -1px;
  z-index: 10;
  content: '';
  right: -15px;
}

ul.nav-wizard li.active:nth-child(-n+2) {
  background: #6633cc;
}

.header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
}

p {
  float: left;
}

.content {
  margin: -29px;
  position: relative;
}

ul.nav-wizard .active ~ li {
  color: #999999;
  background: #ddd;
}

ul.nav-wizard .active ~ li:after {
  border-left: 16px solid #ddd;
}
```

Current JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/zfcm2y27/

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Flexbox**, here's a edited and working version of your 'ul.nav-wizard li' selector, hope it works

```css
ul.nav-wizard li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px 0 30px;
  margin: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 46px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: This helps to bring the content into the list element but the padding is off when adding more to content. It also still keeps the header centered(need it to be left aligned). https://jsfiddle.net/zfcm2y27/5/

Answer (score 0):

Change your .content class to this in your js fiddle :-

```
.content {
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 60px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 left: 0;
 width:100%;
}
```

**Edit :-** for getting text to left  you need to change padding of `ul.nav-wizard li` from `padding: 0 20px 0 30px;` to `padding: 0 20px 0 10px;`

border red is only for reference. remove it. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample. I removed some duplication of element calls and positions and some floats in your CSS file. Is this exactly what you're talking about?

CSS

```
li {
  width: 190px;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 8px;
  color: #999;
}

li:last-child {
  position: relative;
  background: #ddd;
}

li:last-child:after {
  content: '';
  top: -1px;
  right: -15px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 31px solid transparent;
  border-left: 16px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 0;
}

li.active:nth-child(-n+2) {
  background: #6633cc;
}

.header {
  padding: 0 20px 0 30px;
}

.content {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
}
```